# Google Form. Confirmation Email Script. With edit url

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have two working trigger functions in Google Script that fire when a form response spreadsheet gets a new submission. One inserts the "edit your submission" url into the spreadsheet. The other looks up the response's email and sends them a confirmation.

What I'm having a hard time understanding is how to populate the url **first**, and **then** send an email containing that url.

(*Google Script is different to debug than js in the browser :\* )

Setup triggers

```js
function Initialize() {

        var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

        for (var i in triggers) {
            ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
        }

        ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendConfirmationMail")
            .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
            .onFormSubmit()
            .create();

           assignEditUrls();
    }
```

On form submit, searches for column titled "Clients Email", and sends a formatted email to them.

```js
    function SendConfirmationMail(e) {

        try {

            var ss, cc, sendername, subject, columns;
            var message, value, textbody, sender;
            var url;

            // This is your email address and you will be in the CC
            cc = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

            // This will show up as the sender's name
            sendername = "XXXX";

            // Optional but change the following variable
            // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
            subject = "Form Complete: Mobile App - Client Questionnaire";



            // This is the body of the auto-reply
            message = "Confirmation text here.<br><br>Thanks!<br><br>";

            ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
            columns = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

            // This is the submitter's email address
            sender = e.namedValues["Clients Email"].toString();

            // Only include form values that are not blank
            for ( var keys in columns ) {
                var key = columns[keys];
                if ( e.namedValues[key] ) {
                    message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "<br />"; 
                }
            }

            textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n\n");

            GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, 
                                {cc: cc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});

        } catch (e) {
            Logger.log(e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Separate function. Looks up form and applies the edit URL to the 26th column.

```js
    function assignEditUrls() {
      var form = FormApp.openById('10BVYipGhDa_AthabHE-xxxxxx-hg');
        //enter form ID here

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');

        //Change the sheet name as appropriate
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var urlCol = 26; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
      var responses = form.getResponses();
      var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
        urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
      }
      for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

        resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
      }
      sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmers are provided no direct control over the order that trigger functions will be invoked, when they are dependent on the same event.

In your situation though, there are a couple of options available.

1. Use only one trigger function for the event, and have it invoke the current functions in the order you require. (Alternatively, set `assignEditUrls()` up as the only trigger function, and have it call `SendConfirmationMail()` after completing its task.
2. Have `SendConfirmationMail()` check for the availability of the Edit URL, and call [`Utilities.sleep()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep%28Integer%29) if the URL isn't ready yet. (In a loop, until ready.)